# PHP - acquiring array from an object

Tags: php, odbc

In PHP I have this result from MSSQL database:

```
CI_DB_odbc_result Object ( [num_rows] => 5 [conn_id] => Resource id #34 [result_id] => Resource id #49 [result_array] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [NO1] => 119 [NO2] => 115 [NO3] => 123 [NO4] => 127)
```

Can you please tell me how do I access/extract [result_array] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [NO1] => 119 [NO2] => 115 [NO3] => 123 [NO4] => 127) into plain PHP array?

Comment: What stops you from `$result=CI_DB_odbc_result->result_array;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array can be accessed by the object property.

```
$result = CI_DB_odbc_result->result_array;
print_r($result);
```